# "too many values to unpack" error during image segmentation(jpg)

Tags: python, valueerror

```
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image_path = self.image_file[index]
        label_path = self.label_file[index]

        # Read images and labels
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
       
        label = cv2.imread(label_path)
        

        y, x = image.shape
        image = image.astype(dtype=np.float32)
        label = label.astype(dtype=np.float32)
```

I am getting value Error when the getitem block is getting run. The root directory and image directories are mentioned as:

```
    root_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/crack/DATA/"  # todo
    parser.add_argument("--root_dir",
                        default=root_dir,
                        help="the address of the outermost code")

    # information about the image and label
    parser.add_argument(
        "--Tr_Image_dir",
        default=root_dir + "Image_Tr/",
        help="the address of the train image",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--Te_Image_dir",
        default=root_dir + "Image_Te/",
        help="the address of the test image",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--Tr_Label_dir",
        default=root_dir + "Label_Tr/",
        help="the address of the train label",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--Te_Label_dir",
        default=root_dir + "Label_Te/",
        help="the address of the test label",
    )
```

Error:

```
<ipython-input-63-4da441b933f8> in __getitem__(self, index)
24         #label = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(label)
25 
26         y, x = image.shape
27         image = image.astype(dtype=np.float32)
28         label = label.astype(dtype=np.float32)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Your image probably has 3rd dimension, which is responsible for 3 color channels. Try `y, x, _`.